# Split pandas partial rows into two rows according to conditions

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this

| Products | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 500 |
| C | 1000 |
| D | 3000 |
| E | 6000 |

and I want to split two lines with prices between 1000 and 5000, where the first line is price-commission, and the second line is commission, like

| Products | Price |
| --- | --- |
| A | 100 |
| B | 500 |
| C | 900 |
| C | 100 |
| D | 2700 |
| D | 300 |
| E | 6000 |

Comment: Do you want to split it 90%/10% ?

Comment: What is your condition for splitting a line?

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes, 90-10

Comment: @CodeDifferent 1000<= price <= 5000

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Split `Price` column value satisfying the price criterion to a list, then `explode` `Price` column to convert list into multi rows.

```py
df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda price: [price * 0.9, price * 0.1] if 1000 <= price <= 5000 else price)

df_ = df.explode('Price')
```

```
print(df_)

  Products   Price
0        A     100
1        B     500
2        C   900.0
2        C   100.0
3        D  2700.0
3        D   300.0
4        E    6000
```

If your `Products` column is unique before splitting, you can add `Type` info by dropping duplicates to get info about which is `Commission`

```py
m = df_.reset_index().index.isin(df_.reset_index().drop_duplicates('Products', keep='first').index)

df_['Type'] = np.where(m, 'Price', 'Commission')
```

```
print(df_)

  Products   Price        Type
0        A     100       Price
1        B     500       Price
2        C   900.0       Price
3        C   100.0  Commission
4        D  2700.0       Price
5        D   300.0  Commission
6        E    6000       Price
```

Or you can add `Price` and `Commission` info before splitting

```py
df['Type'] = np.where(mask, 'Price-Commission', 'Price')
df['Type'] = df['Type'].str.split('-')

df['Price'] = df['Price'].apply(lambda price: [price * 0.9, price * 0.1] if 1000 <= price <= 5000 else price)

df_ = df.apply(pd.Series.explode)
```

```
print(df_)

  Products   Price        Type
0        A     100       Price
1        B     500       Price
2        C   900.0       Price
3        C   100.0  Commission
4        D  2700.0       Price
5        D   300.0  Commission
6        E    6000       Price
```

Comment: thank you. In addition, what should I do if I want to add a column to distinguish between price and commission?